# FileReader (cordova-plugin-file) failing

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am trying to read and write files using the cordova-plugin-file plugin. Writing the files seems to work fine, but when I go to read the file, it doesn't work and the fail callback that I set up runs.

```
function getData(fetch) {
    alert('Getting data')
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
    fs.root.getFile(department + ".txt", { create: false, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        alert('reading this file: ' + JSON.stringify(fileEntry))
        readFile(fileEntry);
    }, addDepartment);
    });

    if (typeof sessionStorage.currentGroup != 'undefined') {groupData = dataActive[sessionStorage.currentGroup];}
    if (typeof sessionStorage.currentSubgroup != 'undefined') {subgroupData = groupData[sessionStorage.currentSubgroup];}
    if (typeof sessionStorage.currentItem != 'undefined') {itemData = subgroupData[sessionStorage.currentItem];}
    if (typeof itemData != 'undefined') {
    UCC = itemData.UCC;
    GTIN = itemData.GTIN;
    ProductionDate = itemData.ProductionDate;
    Weight = itemData.Weight;
    SerialNum = itemData.SerialNum;
    }
    fetch();
}


function readFile(fileEntry) {
    alert('Reading file')

    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
            window.dataActive = JSON.parse(this.result);
            alert('dataActive was read as: ' + dataActive)
            displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);

    }, alert('failed to read file!'));
}
```

I keep getting "failed to read file" and the rest of the code can't run because there's no data (which I needed from the file). I'm a bit new to JavaScript and PhoneGap/Cordova,

### Update

I have attempted to debug my code because it was full of problems, but now I'm down to the bare minimum and I've double checked everything and I still don't know what the problem is. I've followed the documentation examples so closely (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) and it just won't work. I keep getting null when it reads the file. My code is below:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

    fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(fileEntry))
        // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
        // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
        writeFile(fileEntry, 'sample text');
        readFile(fileEntry);

    }, function() {alert('onErrorCreateFile')});

}, function() {alert('onErrorLoadFs')});

function readFile(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
            //displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);

    }, function() {alert('onErrorReadFile')});
}

function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwrite = function() {
            alert("Successful file write...");
            readFile(fileEntry);
            alert('Contents are: ' + this.result);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            alert("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
        };

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter which you are using is not same as function inside.
Your code should look like this:

```
function readFile(fileEntry) {
    alert('Reading file')

    fileEntry.file(function (fileEntry) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
            window.dataActive = JSON.parse(this.result);
            alert('dataActive was read as: ' + dataActive)
            displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(fileEntry);

    }, alert('failed to read file!'));
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to still be saying "failed to read file" :,(

Comment: @BrettBalhen then debug it, use alert(fileEntry); .. Is it object ?

Comment: Yeah fileEntry is an object with fields including FileSystem:persistent, nativeURL:file:///data/user/0/com.phonegap.helloworld/files/files/data.txt, and fullPath:/data.txt  And file is an object that includes this: localURL:cdvfile://localhost/persistent/data.txt

Comment: It looks like I mostly got it to work by converting the cdv filepath to a native path, but now the result is read as null when it should be "{}" and it somehow stll triggers the failure callback. I'm very confused.

Comment: I pulled the thread and have updated my code (see above) and still have no idea what to do. If you had any insight, I would be very very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it! Honestly, I'm not sure what I did wrong in the first place but after spinning my wheels for what seemed an eternity, I finally got it to work. Here is my code. This is just a sample so it doesn't actually do anything useful, but if someone out there is having the same problem, hopefully this will help them too and they can edit it to work how they need it to.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

    fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile2.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
        // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
        //var sample = new Blob(['some file data'], { type: 'text/plain' }); this works too or you can just use ['some file data'] like below
        writeFile(fileEntry, ['some file data']);

    }, function() {alert('onErrorCreateFile')});

}, function() {alert('onErrorLoadFs')});

function readFile(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {
            alert("Successful file read: " + this.result);
            //displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);

    }, function() {alert('onErrorReadFile')});
}

function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwrite = function() {
            alert("Successful file write...");
            readFile(fileEntry);
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
            alert("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
        };

        fileWriter.write(dataObj);
    });
}
```